# Why I can't passing a variable into page url parameter in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, puppeteer

I got an Error `Error: Protocol error (Page.navigate): Invalid parameters Failed to deserialize params.url - BINDINGS: mandatory field missing at position 49...`

When I passing a variable into page url parameter like this:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const BASE_URL = {
  production: 'https://foo.go.id',
  staging: 'https://foo.staging.com',
  development: 'http://localhost:3001',
}[process.env.NODE_ENV || 'staging'];

async function screenshotPage(bodyReq) {
  const { idElement, pageUrl, isGeneratePDF, token } = bodyReq;

  // Initialize puppeteer
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // Set breakpoint 1080p
  const override = Object.assign(page.viewport(), { width: 1920 });
  await page.setViewport(override);

  // No timeout when generating
  page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);

  /**
   * Error when I passing a variable
   */
  await page.goto(BASE_URL, { waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 0 });
  const screenshot = await page.screenshot()

  return screenshot.toString('base64')
}
```

It's fine when passing the url without variable, but the problem is that different `environment` is different `url`:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const BASE_URL = {
  production: 'https://foo.go.id',
  staging: 'https://foo.staging.com',
  development: 'http://localhost:3001',
}[process.env.NODE_ENV || 'staging'];

async function screenshotPage(bodyReq) {
  const { idElement, pageUrl, isGeneratePDF, token } = bodyReq;

  // Initialize puppeteer
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // Set breakpoint 1080p
  const override = Object.assign(page.viewport(), { width: 1920 });
  await page.setViewport(override);

  // No timeout when generating
  page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);

  /**
   * How can I know if the current environment is staging, production, or development
   * if I can't passing a variable
   */
  await page.goto('https://foo.staging.com', { waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 0 });
  const screenshot = await page.screenshot()

  return screenshot.toString('base64')
}
```

Comment: have you tried using `ternary` operator? Like `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'some_url' : 'other_url'`

Comment: I ran your code here with no change and I got `Error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED at https://foo.staging.com`

Comment: @AngularSan Thx it's work

Comment: I am sorry @MestreSan it's a Fake/Sample urls

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using string template literals?

```js
await page.goto(`${BASE_URL}`, { waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 0 });
```